# c function free() for matrix

Tags: c, memory-management

I am working on an pure c project for school.

```
char** init_matrix ( )
{
    printf ( "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    char** temp_matrix;
    temp_matrix = ( char ** ) malloc ( CHAR_BIT * sizeof (char* ) );
    for ( int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i ++ )
    {
        *( temp_matrix + i ) = ( char * ) calloc ( CHAR_BIT, sizeof (char ) );
    }

    return temp_matrix;
}
```

somewhere in main i have a call,

```
char ** mat = init_matrix ( );
```

Is free cascading to all pointers pointed

```
free(mat);
```

or should i do a for loop again for every pointer defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "pure" C (as compared to "impure" C, perhaps)? I see use of `malloc()` and `calloc()` which do not conform to the C language standard. You should not cast the results. `free()` doesn't cascade. If you want to write your own function for freeing your matrices, you should use the `for` loop to free _every single pointer defined_.

Comment: the 'free' function does not 'cascade' The code must pass each pointer that was returned from any memory allocation function call to `free()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is free cascading to all pointers pointed

No.

> should i do a for loop again for every pointer defined?

Yes.

The general rule is:

1 call to `free()` per 1 call to `malloc()` or its friends (`calloc()`, `realloc()`, `strdup()`).

Where a call to `realloc()` on an already re/allocated piece of memory does not count.